# In VHDL, what does RHS of generic map assignment refer to?

Tags: generics, vhdl, fpga

Based on my understanding of VHDL, a port map declaration will be:

```
signal reset_n : std_logic;

...

port map (
    ...
    reset_n => reset_n
);
```

... where the LHS of the port map assignment is the port name on your component and the RHS is a signal you've declared above.

But for a generic map, what does the RHS refer to?

```
...
generic map (
    ...
    baud_rate => baud_rate
);
```

The LHS is the generic field in the entity to be written to by whatever the RHS specifies (right?), the VHDL way of passing a value into your generic. But if the RHS is not declared as a signal, what is being assigned/wired to the LHS? What is going on under the hood?

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.7 Association lists, 6.5.7.2 Generic map aspects, 6.5.7.1 General "An association list, other than one appearing in an interface package generic map aspect (see 6.5.5), establishes correspondences between formal or local generic, port, or parameter names on the one hand and ***local or actual names, expressions, subtypes, subprograms, or packages on the other***."

Comment: 6.5.6 Interface lists, 6.5.6.1 "A *generic* interface list consists entirely of interface constant declarations, interface type declarations, interface subprogram declarations, and interface package declarations. A *port* interface list consists entirely of interface signal declarations. A *parameter* interface list may contain interface constant declarations, interface signal declarations, interface variable declarations, interface file declarations, or any combination thereof."

Comment: -1 You posted the same question on two forums near simultaneous. That is against the rules , impolite and very much frowned upon.

Comment: @Oldfart, to what *rules* are referring?

Comment: I fail to see what harm there is in posting to two separate forums when I have a valid question for two very different audiences and received very different responses from each, both valuable. By this logic, I shouldn't post the same question on Xilinx or Lattice forums either. I recommend spending the afternoon searching for whatever cross-posted questions I may or may not have placed elsewhere on the internet. And don't stop at this question. Definitely go back through my others.

Comment: Finding *rules* prohibiting posting the same question on multiple Stack Exchange forums may be problematic (some forums do have restrictions in their guidelines, not SO). You can at least infer that doing so is *very much frowned upon*,  see  [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).  The reason for putting it on hold on EESE was it was off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, the LHS is called the *formal* and the RHS is called the *actual*.

The *formal* refers to the constant you declared in your entity.

```
entity foo is
  generic (
    constant baud_rate : T_BAUD
  );
end entity;
```

The *actual* is *associated* in a *generic map* to a *formal*. As in your case the *actual* is a constant, you can either associate:

- another generic constant from a higher layer
- a constant declared in an architetcure declarative region or a global constant declared in a package
- an expression, including a literal.

Examples:

```
entity e is
  generic (
    baudrate : T_BAUD
  );
end entity;

architecture a of e is
  constant BR : T_BAUD := 100 kBd;
begin
  inst1: entity work.foo
    generic map (
      baud_rate => baudrate
    );
  inst2: entity work.foo
    generic map (
      baud_rate => BR
    );
  inst3: entity work.foo
    generic map (
      baud_rate => 115.2 KBd
    );
end architecture;
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. Thank you. The term 'formal' also applies to constants/values declared in a component? I want to make sure my lingo is correct.

Comment: Note that the second "LHS" in the first sentence should be "RHS". The system won't let me fix this simple but fundamental typo directly.

Comment: Getting the *lingo* correct requires some degree of inculcation, the standard is a formal specification and there are inter-dependencies relying on applying concise definitions. If you're not using -2008 features IEEE Std 1076-1993 is easier to use as a reference (640 pages versus 249 pages). If you use protected types see the -2002 revision (309 pages). LHS and RHS are not terms of art in VHDL.

Comment: @user1155120 *left-hand side* is used by for example in IEEE Std. 1076-2008 in 1.3.2 c) or 9.2.1 :)

Comment: @schadjo The term *left-hand* is commonly used in descriptions of computer languages to describe a) the target of an assignment or b) to refer to one of the operands in an expression. So even if VHDL is using formal and actual, *LHS* and *RHS* is common terminus when dealing with grammars and computer languages.

Comment: And yet LHS and RHS are not found in the VHDL standard *lingo*.